# What is vendor_audit and why is it spamming my logs?

Tags: logging, processes, spam

I have an app spamming my logcat messages and I assume it is responsible for slow operation of my device. The logs all look like this and there are thousands:

```
2022-01-18 18:02:19.204 646-646/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1642345453.765:312963): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=1173 comm=87654F456789656Z646C1234567890 name="gpuclk" dev="sysfs" ino=74938 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_sysfs_kgsl_gpuclk:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 SEPF_SV-X825_11_0010 audit_filtered
```

I used `adb shell ps -A` to list my processes and the spamming PID is the following line:

```
vendor_audit    646      1 2142068   2592 0                   0 S auditd
```

Also I checked the other PID mentioned in the log, it's this one:

```
system         1173    673 11627288 282980 0                  0 S system_server
```

*Note: I do not know what all these numbers in the log output are, I assume some random device identifiers and similar. Just to be on the safe side, I changed them before uploading, but I kept the length the same. I left the PID numbers*

Device is a Galaxy Tab S5e with the preinstalled system, not rooted.

Comment: It's not the app. `auditd` and `system_server` are the core operating system processes. `vendor_audit` and `system` are their UIDs respectively. And the `audit` log entries belong to SELinux which is the core Mandatory Access Control mechanism in Android. You cannot control this logging, at least without root. Contact your ROM manufacturer if you find this a bug.

Comment: Some device are very verbose on logcat for example I had once a Samsung device that produced ~50 log entries per second in idle state and up to 4 times when using an app.

Comment: From [your previous question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/234390/44325), is this on Samsung Galaxy S9? Otherwise, might also help to mention the device model and whether it's rooted and/or using custom ROM.

Comment: @AndrewT. I added the device information, good point thanks.